# Android Intent to open Email application from separate class?

Tags: android, android-intent

I've got a TabHost application where the user can send an email from any of the tab activities. I want to write one class which can be instantiated from any of the activities which will handle launching the Email intent but not sure this is the ideal way to do it.

Although It saves some code duplication, it seems like a lot of overhead having to create an intent which creates another intent to launch createChooser(). Is there a better way?

Application code

```
Intent send = new Intent (this, Email.class); 
send.putExtra ("mailto", EMAIL_ADDRESS); 
send.putExtra ("subject", SUBJECT); 
send.putExtra ("body", MSG_BODY); 
this.startActivity (send);
```

Email class

```
public class Email extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        Log.d ("email" , " oncreate");

        Bundle ex = getIntent ().getExtras ();
        String mailto =  ex.getString ("mailto");
        String subject = ex.getString ("subject");
        String body = ex.getString ("body");

        if (body == null)
           body = "";
        if (subject == null)
           subject = "";

        try
        { 
            // use the builtin chooser for users mail app or SMS
            /* NOTE: AndroidManifest has android:noHistory="true" for this */
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String [] {mailto});
            sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
            startActivityForResult (Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send via which Application?"), 0);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText (this, "No activity was found to handle this action",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so as it turns out, this was rather trivial. The sticky part was passing the Context and launching the intent from it.  Hope it helps someone else.

```
package foo.test.email;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Email
    {

        public static void send (Context ctx, String addy, String subject, String body)
        {
            try
            {
                // use the builtin chooser for users 'send' app
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

                sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String [] {addy});
                sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

                ctx.startActivity (Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send via which Application?"));
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Toast.makeText (ctx, "No activity was found to handle this action",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

and to call the static send method from another class:

```
Email.send (mainApp.this, "who@where", "a subject", "a body");
```

Comment: `startActivity()` is a method on `Context`, so you do not need to cast it. Also `mainApp.this` is the same as `mainApp`, so you can drop the `.this` part.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've updated the code. I'm calling Email.send() from MainApp's OnItemClickListener. If I don't specifically use "MainApp.this", Eclipse thinks "this" is referring to (near as I can tell) the OnItemClickListener and not MainApp Context. I guess it could be done using getBaseContext() as well?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that. You will want `MainApp.this` then.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to write one class which can be instantiated from any of the activities which will handle launching the Email intent but not sure this is the ideal way to do it.

Since your code does not work, it is certainly not the ideal way to do it.

> Is there a better way?

Use a static method. Pass your subject, etc. as parameters to the method. Have the method call `startActivity()` on your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` (note: do not bother calling `startActivityForResult()`, as `ACTION_SEND` is not designed to work with `startActivityForResult()`).

Comment: Oh, it probably isn't working for you as I left out the import sections for brevity. You would need to add those first. I tried making a static method for 'send()' but since Activity isn't static itself, I'm not able to call startActivity() in a static method. Thanks though, I will poke around some more.

Comment: @wufoo: "I left out the import sections for brevity" -- no, you have more fundamental problems than that. If you try passing data to yourself via `Intent` extras, it is often useful to read that data back out of the extras, which you are not doing. "I'm not able to call startActivity() in a static method" -- sure you are. Pass in a suitable `Context` (e.g., an existing `Activity` instance) as a parameter to your static method.

Comment: *facepalm* I see what you mean now. Yeah, I left out an edit I made while I was in the process of posting. I'll update the code.