# How to open emailIntent without using chooser but having default account to send email

Tags: java, android, email, default

I apologize if it's a repeated question but the answers that i found doesn't work for me. What i want is to open email Intent with chooser dialog but directly send email using emailClient that i set as default in settings of device:-

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);


                emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                String contactEmail = directoryDetails.getEmail();


                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ contactEmail});

                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");

                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");

                activity.startActivity(emailIntent);
```

It's using a fixed email that i setup very first one. but not variaying according to default  settings. Can anybody say what i am missing in my code.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693566/android-intent-to-open-email-application-from-separate-class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255915/android-intent-chooser-to-only-show-e-mail-option

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:someone@example.com?subject=" +
    Uri.encode("my subject") +  "&body=" +
    Uri.encode("My big long body with spaces, new lines, and all sorts of invalid URI characters"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Ok, it's fine to do so & it's avoiding Chooser-screen but it's only considering GMAIL accounts but not EMAIL accounts. I am using HTC one V.

Comment: have you configure that mail account

Comment: yes, i did configure. I configured 2-Email account & 2-Gmail accounts. I am only able to switch between gmail account but not between email-accounts.

Comment: try this :-     Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.email");
  startActivity(intent);

Comment: are you checked this answer.