# How to show available mail apps in my phone

Tags: android, android-studio, email, android-intent

I'm trying to open the email app from my app, for that I'm using the below code to open.
But it only opens the Gmail app, I have installed the outlook and yahoo mail apps.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Can anyone help, need to show the available mail apps.(Gmail, outlook, yahoo)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Intent to open Email application from separate class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693566/android-intent-to-open-email-application-from-separate-class)

Comment: No @Cheesebaron

Comment: Why does intent chooser not work for you?